# Questions about Arrays / Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, arrays, split

```
var icons = $(".IT_Icon").text().trim().split(",");
```

Above, portions of the text of the element, between commas, is broken up and stored in an array. If i wanted to wrap or append or do anything to an item in the source list, how would i do that?

For example:

before:

```
[cat, dog, mouse, elephant, lion, bird]
```

after:

```
<img src="cat"/>, <img src="dog"/>, <img src="mouse"/>, <img src="elephant"/>, <img src="lion"/>, <img src="bird"/>
```

On second thought, couldn't i just have a regex that finds the 'parts' of the list, what's between commas, and supplements it with whatever i need? Whether that be wrapping, or a replacement?

*ANSWER*

This is what i ended up with:

```
$(".IT_badge").each(function () {
    var badges = $(this).text().trim().split(",");

$(this).html("");

    for (i = 0; badges.length > i; i++) {
        $(this).append($("<img/>").attr("src", 'IT_Badges/' + badges[i] + '.png'));

        if (!(badges.length === i+1)) {
            $(this).append(", ");           
        }
    }


});
```

Comment: What do you mean by *wrapping* an item?

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this, but a bit more information would be useful.  How are you deciding which one to replace?  In the example, is it replacing "elephant" with "GUESS", is it replacing the 4th entry with GUESS?  etc.  And then what is being done with this after the replace?  Is the intent just to update the text in the span?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the text of a span?

Comment: @hunter @ Felix Kling - I ultimately want to 'convert' the words in the comma list into icons, thus i would want to 'wrap' the words in img scr="' + word + '"/>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favorite way to do this is simply:

```
str = '<img src="' + ary.join('"/><img src="') + '"/>';
```

which will give you a single string of image tags.  If you want to do it in jQuery, something like:

```
(".IT_Icon").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html('<img src="' + $this.text() + '"/>');
});
```

Are you trying to get a string?  amend the HTML?

Comment: The first way kinda works. If there's only one item in the array then it breaks and doesn't look good. The second way almost works too, but it doesn't produce more than one icon img.

Comment: I got it to work. I selected yours as the correct one even though my script is quite different, simply because yours employs similar functions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use `Array.prototype.map` which you can easily create if your browser does not support it.

```
if (!Array.prototype.map)
{
  Array.prototype.map = function(fun /*, thisp */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array(len);
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
        res[i] = fun.call(thisp, t[i], i, t);
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var newIcons = icons.map(function(v) {
    return "<img src='" + v + ".png' />";
});
```

Comment: I would defiantly recommend using `$.map` or `_.map` instead of extending `Array.prototype`

Comment: @Raynos - The advantage of this method is that any native implementation will be lightning quick. Firefox 3.5+ supports this natively and IE9+ does. Also your comment leaves me unsure as to why you think your option is better.

Comment: @ChaosPandion `$.map` and `_.map` delegate to the native maps by feature detection. These implementations are quite clever. Extending native prototypes is the devil.

Comment: @Raynos - Why is it the *"devil"* as you so eloquently put it?

Comment: @ChaosPandion it messes with the state of native objects. It breaks code that makes assumption about Array.prototype. It's bad for the same reason extending Object.prototype is bad, it breaks `for ... in` loops.

Comment: @Raynos - I hear that argument touted often and I feel it has minimal merit. When dealing with a dynamic language you sacrifice type safety for simplicity and elegance. You could pass me any custom object and I can change it if I so desire. Why handicap yourself by ignoring one of the key features of the language?

Comment: @ChaosPandion because you want code to live together nicely in one place. If you sandbox the _native_ Array then you can mess with it all you want. If you extend it with the "enumerable" flag set to false then you can mess with it all you want. For sanity of using many pieces of 3rd party code together with my own I don't want any of them to touch native prototypes. Besides it has everything to do with lack of type safety. I do a `for ... in` loop on an `Object` I don't care whether it is a `Function`, `String` or an `Array`.

Comment: @Raynos - I was just browsing the jQuery source and it seems that their map implementation does not fallback to the native method. It also seems to flattens nested arrays which I would consider a bit of a surprise from an API perspective.

Comment: Why would you rewrite a map implementation when it is included with jQuery?

Comment: @ChaosPandion jQuery's map function is too different from the native to use it. It has a different API then Array.prototype.map. If the return value is `null` or `undefined` it get's removed from the array (>_<). @maerics don't troll. So basically use _.map :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function:

```
var s1 = [cat, dog, mouse, elephant, lion, bird];
var s2 = $.map(s1, function(x) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = x;
  return img;
});
s2; // => [<img src="cat"/>, <img src="dog"/>, ..., <img src="bird"/>];
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var icons = $(".IT_Icon").text().trim().split(",");

$.each(icons, function(i, e){
    $("#container").append($("<img/>", { src: $.trim(e) }));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/e8Vhj/